# Regression model similar to neuron action potential?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

On the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depolarization) for depolarization they show a plot of the action potential in a neuron exhibiting depolarization. See below.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/1221_Action_Potential.jpg]

I am actually modelling gene expression over time, and some of the genes in my data have a time-dependence similar to the plot above. The key features of this curve that interest me:

1. Initial baseline.
2. Asymmetric peak.
3. Drop below baseline after peak.
4. Monotonic increase back to baseline.

Is there a parametric model for this kind of time-dependence curve?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a parametric model for an action potential but using Fourier analysis you can get a decomposition in sines or cosines that may recreate your curve very accurately. To do that you need to digitize the curve you are showing and get the Fourier spectrum.The book I used  decades ago is "The FFT, Fundamentals and Concepts" by Robert W. Ramirez. It is good but I am sure there are more updated sources.